# How can I save an MLMultiArray to a file

Tags: ios, swift, multidimensional-array, coreml

For debug reasons, I need to save the content of a big MLMultiarray as a file.

I need an accuracy of up to 0.0001.
Saving the entire matrix as a JSON file is impossible as it is too big (1.5G).
I Assume that a binary representation or a compressed representation will be x5 or x20 smaller.
As this is a debug code it can be somewhat slow.

Any idea?

Comment: Why don't you just compress the text with zip or something?

Comment: @Joshua Lacock, I do not want to have an intermediate 1.5GB file.
Do you know of a way to directly write a compressed ZIP file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of encoding the huge MLMultiArray which cause a memory overloading, you can iterate over it and write it as stream to a file in JSON format:

First you should add FileStreamer.swift which responsible for writing:

```
import Foundation

class FileStreamer {
    
    private let fileURL: URL
    let fileHandle: FileHandle

    init(fileURL: URL) {
        self.fileURL = fileURL
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path) {
            try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: fileURL)
        }
        FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: fileURL.path, contents: nil, attributes: nil)
        self.fileHandle = FileHandle(forWritingAtPath: fileURL.path)!
    }

    func write(_ string: String) {
        fileHandle.seekToEndOfFile()
        if let data = string.data(using: .utf8) {
            fileHandle.write(data)
        }
    }
    
    func close() {
        try? fileHandle.close()
    }
}
```

Then you can add MLMultiArray helper which embeds the MLMultiArray and has the ability to write it as a JSON format.

```
    //
//  MultiArray.swift
//
//  Created by Tal Sahar on 16/05/2022.
//

import Foundation
import CoreML
import Swift

public protocol MultiArrayType: Comparable {
  static var multiArrayDataType: MLMultiArrayDataType { get }
  static func +(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
  static func -(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
  static func *(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
  static func /(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
  init(_: Int)
  var toUInt8: UInt8 { get }
}

extension Double: MultiArrayType {
  public static var multiArrayDataType: MLMultiArrayDataType { return .double }
  public var toUInt8: UInt8 { return UInt8(self) }
}

extension Float: MultiArrayType {
  public static var multiArrayDataType: MLMultiArrayDataType { return .float32 }
  public var toUInt8: UInt8 { return UInt8(self) }
}

extension Int32: MultiArrayType {
  public static var multiArrayDataType: MLMultiArrayDataType { return .int32 }
  public var toUInt8: UInt8 { return UInt8(self) }
}


/**
 Wrapper around MLMultiArray to make it more Swifty.
*/
public struct MultiArray<T: MultiArrayType> {
  public let array: MLMultiArray
  public let pointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<T>

  private(set) public var strides: [Int]
  private(set) public var shape: [Int]

  /**
   Creates a new multi-array filled with all zeros.
  */
  public init(shape: [Int]) {
    let m = try! MLMultiArray(shape: shape as [NSNumber], dataType: T.multiArrayDataType)
    self.init(m)
    memset(pointer, 0, MemoryLayout<T>.stride * count)
  }

  /**
   Creates a new multi-array initialized with the specified value.
  */
  public init(shape: [Int], initial: T) {
    self.init(shape: shape)
    for i in 0..<count {
      pointer[i] = initial
    }
  }

  /**
   Creates a multi-array that wraps an existing MLMultiArray.
  */
  public init(_ array: MLMultiArray) {
    self.init(array, array.shape as! [Int], array.strides as! [Int])
  }

  init(_ array: MLMultiArray, _ shape: [Int], _ strides: [Int]) {
    self.array = array
    self.shape = shape
    self.strides = strides
    pointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<T>(OpaquePointer(array.dataPointer))
  }

  /**
   Returns the number of elements in the entire array.
  */
  public var count: Int {
    return shape.reduce(1, *)
  }

  public subscript(a: Int) -> T {
    get { return pointer[a] }
    set { pointer[a] = newValue }
  }

  public subscript(a: Int, b: Int) -> T {
    get { return pointer[a*strides[0] + b*strides[1]] }
    set { pointer[a*strides[0] + b*strides[1]] = newValue }
  }

  public subscript(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int) -> T {
    get { return pointer[a*strides[0] + b*strides[1] + c*strides[2]] }
    set { pointer[a*strides[0] + b*strides[1] + c*strides[2]] = newValue }
  }

  public subscript(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int, d: Int) -> T {
    get { return pointer[a*strides[0] + b*strides[1] + c*strides[2] + d*strides[3]] }
    set { pointer[a*strides[0] + b*strides[1] + c*strides[2] + d*strides[3]] = newValue }
  }

  public subscript(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int, d: Int, e: Int) -> T {
    get { return pointer[a*strides[0] + b*strides[1] + c*strides[2] + d*strides[3] + e*strides[4]] }
    set { pointer[a*strides[0] + b*strides[1] + c*strides[2] + d*strides[3] + e*strides[4]] = newValue }
  }

  public subscript(indices: [Int]) -> T {
    get { return pointer[offset(for: indices)] }
    set { pointer[offset(for: indices)] = newValue }
  }

  func offset(for indices: [Int]) -> Int {
    var offset = 0
    for i in 0..<indices.count {
      offset += indices[i] * strides[i]
    }
    return offset
  }
}

extension MultiArray {
    
    func write(to stream: FileStreamer) {
        write(to: stream, [])
    }
    
    private func write(to stream: FileStreamer, _ indices: [Int]) {

        // This function is called recursively for every dimension.
        // Add an entry for this dimension to the end of the array.
        var indices = indices + [0]

        let d = indices.count - 1          // the current dimension
        let N = shape[d]                   // how many elements in this dimension
        stream.write("[")
        if indices.count < shape.count {   // not last dimension yet?
          for i in 0..<N {
            indices[d] = i
            write(to: stream, indices)
            if i != N - 1 {
                stream.write(",")
            }
          }
        } else {                           // the last dimension has actual data
          for i in 0..<N {
            indices[d] = i
              stream.write("\(self[indices])")
            if i != N - 1 {                // not last element?
                stream.write(",")
            }
          }
        }
        stream.write("]")
    }
}

extension MultiArray: CustomStringConvertible {
  public var description: String {
    return description([])
  }

  func description(_ indices: [Int]) -> String {
    func indent(_ x: Int) -> String {
      return String(repeating: " ", count: x)
    }

    // This function is called recursively for every dimension.
    // Add an entry for this dimension to the end of the array.
    var indices = indices + [0]

    let d = indices.count - 1          // the current dimension
    let N = shape[d]                   // how many elements in this dimension
    var s = "["
    if indices.count < shape.count {   // not last dimension yet?
      for i in 0..<N {
        indices[d] = i
        s += description(indices)      // then call recursively again
        if i != N - 1 {
          s += ",\n" + indent(d + 1)
        }
      }
    } else {                           // the last dimension has actual data
      s += " "
      for i in 0..<N {
        indices[d] = i
        s += "\(self[indices])"
        if i != N - 1 {                // not last element?
          s += ", "
          if i % 11 == 10 {            // wrap long lines
            s += "\n " + indent(d + 1)
          }
        }
      }
      s += " "
    }
    return s + "]"
  }
}
```

Now you can write any size of MLMultiArray to a file while keeping your memory usage constant.

Usage:

```
let descriptorsFileStream = FileStreamer(fileURL: <#PATH#>)
descriptors.writeCompressed(to: descriptorsFileStream)
descriptorsFileStream.close()
```